# How to open json file in google drive in colab

Tags: python, json, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I want to open the json file in my google drive with the google colab. But there is an error.

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
os.chdir("/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks")
os.listdir()

['keras.ipynb',
 'ItemData.json',
 'DropData.json',
 'DefaultUserData.json',
 'MonsterData.json',
 'DungenData.json',
 'EquipData.json',
 'UserData.json',
 'game balancing.ipynb']
```

there is surely 'itemData.json' file 
But when I'm trying to open ...

```py
with open('itemData.json') as json_file:
    itemData = json.load(json_file)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-da912edd7528> in <module>()
----> 1 with open('itemData.json') as json_file:
      2     itemData = json.load(json_file)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'itemData.json'
```

what's the problem???

Answer (score 2):

Try making the correct case.

```
'itemData.json'
```

must be

```
'ItemData.json'
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant access 'itemData.json' just by name
so you have to provide the location
with open(f'{path}/{data}') as json_file:
itemData =json.load(json_file)

here path is "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks"
and data is 'itemData.json'